# How to fix NoClassDefFoundError: CircularOutputStream error?

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, headless

I was just creating a simple maven project for Selenium WebDriver(a.k.a. Selenium 2) automated test for headless testing. I added the PhantomJS driver dependency as follows with other dependencies in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.detro</groupId>
    <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But it is getting error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/io/CircularOutputStream
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.<init>(FirefoxBinary.java:60)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.<init>(FirefoxBinary.java:56)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
at jp.co.skygate.home.HomePageLogin.setUp(HomePageLogin.java:108)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at
```

Just removing the PhantomJS dependency from the pom.xml solves the problem and it executes fine.
Can someone help me find the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At last I got the solution.

Adding PhantomJS v.1.2.0 replaces the selenium-remote-driver-2.53.0.jar with selenium-remote-driver-2.41.0.jar and hence breaks down everything.
And now using V.2.41.0,

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

instead of

```
driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
```

generates the error.

Comment: So, it was the version compatibility issue. You can use phantomjsdriver 1.3.0 with selenium-remote-driver-2.53.0

Answer (score 0):

As per [@Ripon comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36586726/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-openqa-selenium-io-circular-outputstream#comment61295934_36591366), the problem is in version compatibility, so Selenium Server 2.53.x should be used along with Phantom JS 1.3.x .

Here is lines in the `pom.xml` which should work:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>2.53.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
  <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then run `mvn dependency:tree` to build and display the dependency tree for this project.

If you're not using Maven, you need to [make sure you've all dependent jar files in your `classpath`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40009527/55075).