# CircularOutputStream class not found exception when using Selenium with Mozilla's GeckoDriver

Tags: java, selenium, geckodriver

I got a problem when I use Java Selenium Firefox geckodriver. Here is the problem:

*OS: Windows 7

*Selenium Version: Selenium 3.0.0 beta4

*Java: 8

*Geckodriver: v0.10.0

> Error msg:
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/internal/CircularOutputStream
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.(FirefoxBinary.java:56)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.(FirefoxBinary.java:52)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:92)
>       at tools.Cadencie.LoginCad(Cadencie.java:24)
>       at tools.Cadencie.main(Cadencie.java:73)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.CircularOutputStream
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       ... 10 more

Code:

```
public class Cadencie {

static WebDriver driver;

public void LoginCad(){

    //System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\geckodriver.exe");

    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("http://172.16.1.133:8090/CADENCIE/servlet/app");

    try {

        Thread.sleep(1000);

    } catch(InterruptedException e){

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    Utilities.switchToWindow("Cadencie - User Logon [LOGON]", driver);

    try{

        Thread.sleep(2000);

    } catch(InterruptedException e){

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    driver.findElement(By.id("idBANK")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("idBANK")).sendKeys("48");

    driver.findElement(By.id("idEMPLOYEE")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("idEMPLOYEE")).sendKeys("200003");

    driver.findElement(By.id("idPASSWORD")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("idPASSWORD")).sendKeys("Cadencie1");

    driver.findElement(By.id("maintLOGON")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.id("idPASSWORD")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("idPASSWORD")).sendKeys("Cadencie1");

    driver.findElement(By.id("maint")).click();

}
```

I think it might be an inconsistent version issue. Because I have another automation project which is using maven, selenium 2.52.0.. But not sure if this caused the problem. I'm not using maven this time. Just try to create a JAVA GUI program (tool kit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exception is because of missing jar files in `classpath`.

If you don't use Maven, check the [Compile Dependencies at MVN Repository page](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-firefox-driver/3.0.0-beta1) and manually add the jars to your class path.

If you're using Maven, see: [java.lang.classnotfoundexception: org.openqa.selenium.io.Circular OutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36586726/55075)

Comment: Hi Ravthiru, Thanks for the help. Could you please clarify what jars am I missing. Cause I didn't find any hint from IDE.

Comment: Check in Compile Dependencies in this location  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server/3.0.0-beta4

Comment: Thank you very much. Problem Solved.